# Excel Pivot Table_Same column and row item with more than one values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like this

[image]

I hope I can get the latest value when a product has more than one value in a same measurement item by excel pivot table. Like this:
[image]

I tried so hard but still have no way to achieve this...
Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add your source data to the Data Model (via the Power Pivot ribbon), after which you can create the following measures:

**Weight**

```
VAR LatestDate =
    MAXX( 'Table', IF( 'Table'[measure item] = "weight", 'Table'[time] ) )
RETURN
    MAXX(
        'Table',
        IF(
            'Table'[measure item] = "weight",
            IF( 'Table'[time] = LatestDate, 'Table'[value] )
        )
    )
```

**Height**

```
VAR LatestDate =
    MAXX( 'Table', IF( 'Table'[measure item] = "height", 'Table'[time] ) )
RETURN
    MAXX(
        'Table',
        IF(
            'Table'[measure item] = "height",
            IF( 'Table'[time] = LatestDate, 'Table'[value] )
        )
    )
```

Create a Pivot Table with these two measures in the Values field together with *product name* in the Rows field.